# error finding number of days between 2 dates

Tags: php

I tried to find number of days between 2 pre-1970 dates,

```
$ref = strtotime("1776-08-08");
$date = strtotime("1968-12-07");

$day_diff =floor(($date - $ref)/(60*60*24));

echo $day_diff;


// output i got:
-390

//should be 
70247
```

Comment: cant use strtotime for pre  January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC ates

Comment: From the docs: *...not all platforms support negative timestamps, therefore your date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix epoch. This means that e.g. dates prior to Jan 1, 1970 will not work on Windows, some Linux distributions, and a few other operating systems. PHP 5.1.0 and newer versions overcome this limitation though.*

Answer (score 3):

From [the manual for `strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/strtotime)

> The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.) Additionally, not all platforms support negative timestamps, therefore your date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix epoch. This means that e.g. dates prior to Jan 1, 1970 will not work on Windows, some Linux distributions, and a few other operating systems. PHP 5.1.0 and newer versions overcome this limitation though.

This means `strtotime()` won't work for dates prior to December 13, 1901 *at best* and January 1, 1970 *at worst*. Fortunately PHP offers a solution to over come this. You can use [`DateTime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) for dates outside of `strtotime()`'s capabilities:

```
$date1 = new DateTime('1776-08-08');
$date2 = new DateTime('1968-12-07');
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $interval->format('%a days'); // 70247
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9xQzJy)

Answer (score 2):

The `strtotime` function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.

https://www.php.net/strtotime

You should use `DateTime` class instead of `strtotime` function

NOTE : `DateTime` class will work `>=5.2.0`

```
$ref = new DateTime("1776-08-08");
$date = new DateTime("1968-12-07");

$diff = $ref->diff($date);

echo $diff->format('%a');
```

OR for full object

```
print_r($diff)
```

Comment: Again, how does this solve the problem? Make it into an answer.  This is just informational, and as it stands should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Better.  Now what if they don't have PHP 5.2+?